# How do I extract proceeding value using regular expression?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am selecting from an oracle table (using sql) that contains the following values:

```
ae0.32767  
bcm0.0  
em0.0  
ge-0/1/0.32767  
ge-7/1/0.100  
ge-7/1/0.32767  
lo0.0  
lsi.0  
pc-0/0/0.16383  
pc-1/0/0.16383  
pc-5/0/0.16383  
xe-0/0/0.838
```

How do I extract values (using regexp) after and not including the decimal point.

For example:

```
32767  
0  
0  
32767  
100  
32767  
0  
0  
16383  
16383  
16383  
838
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [regexp_substr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#i1239858) function can be used to extract digits after a period at the end of a string. Here is an example:

```
 -- sample of data from your question
 SQL> with t1  as (
  2    select 'ae0.32767' as col from dual union all
  3    select 'bcm0.0'          from dual union all
  4    select 'em0.0'           from dual union all
  5    select 'ge-0/1/0.32767'  from dual union all
  6    select 'ge-7/1/0.100'    from dual union all
  7    select 'ge-7/1/0.32767'  from dual union all
  8    select 'lo0.0'           from dual union all
  9    select 'lsi.0'           from dual union all
 10    select 'pc-0/0/0.16383'  from dual union all
 11    select 'pc-1/0/0.16383'  from dual union all
 12    select 'pc-5/0/0.16383'  from dual union all
 13    select 'xe-0/0/0.838'    from dual
 14  )
 15  select regexp_substr(col, '(\.)([[:digit:]]+)$', 1,1,'i',2) res
 16    from t1
 17  ;

RES
--------------------------------------------------------
32767
0
0
32767
100
32767
0
0
16383
16383
16383
838

12 rows selected
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with substr and instr to get the desired output, something like as follows

```
SELECT  SUBSTR ('ge-0/1/0.32767',
                      INSTR ('ge-0/1/0.32767', '.') + 1,
                      LENGTH ('ge-0/1/0.32767') - INSTR ('ge-0/1/0.32767', '.')
                     )
  FROM  DUAL
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5093c/1)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the programming language. Generally this regex matches the numbers after the decimal point:

```
\.(?<wanted>\d+)
```

You can remove the initial dot from the matched results, or if your language supports named groups capturing (e.g., C# does) you can capture those numbers with `\1`, `$1`, or groups named `"wanted"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex as

```
   \\.(\\d+\\s*)
```

For each match found, use(print) the group 1.

e.g. in **JAVA**:

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.(\\d+\\s*)");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ae0.32767 bcm0.0 em0.0 ge-0/1/0.32767 "+
                                        "ge-7/1/0.100 ge-7/1/0.32767 lo0.0 lsi.0 "+
                                        "pc-0/0/0.16383 pc-1/0/0.16383 "+
                                        "pc-5/0/0.16383 xe-0/0/0.838");
  while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  }
```

prints:

> 32767 
>   0 
>   0 
>   32767 
>   100 
>   32767 
>   0 
>   0 
>   16383 
>   16383 
>   16383 
>   838

Answer (score 0):

you could use: `'s/.*\.\(.*\)/\1/'`

```
> cat temp
ae0.32767  
bcm0.0  
em0.0  
ge-0/1/0.32767  
ge-7/1/0.100  
ge-7/1/0.32767  
lo0.0  
lsi.0  
pc-0/0/0.16383  
pc-1/0/0.16383  
pc-5/0/0.16383  
xe-0/0/0.838 
> sed 's/.*\.\(.*\)/\1/' temp
32767  
0  
0  
32767  
100  
32767  
0  
0  
16383  
16383  
16383  
838 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik positive lookbehind does not work in Oracle SQL so you have to use some regexp_replace or regexp_substr. The exact regular expression though may depend on the source of your data. I've assumed you have a column containing exactly what you showed us; one way could be:

```
create table tmp_test (s varchar2(100));
insert into tmp_test values ('bcm0.0');
insert into tmp_test values ('ge-0/1/0.32767');
select substr(regexp_substr(s, '\.\d+$'), 2) from tmp_test; -- or
select regexp_replace(s, '^.*\.(\d+)$', '\1') from tmp_test;
```

if your text is not alone you have to change a bit the regex, in particular removing the "anchors" ^ and $. Something like

```
insert into tmp_test values ('this is the ge-0/1/0.32767 fact');
select substr(regexp_substr(s, '\.\d+'), 2) from tmp_test;
select regexp_replace(s, '.*\.(\d+).*', '\1') from tmp_test;
```

Comment: and assuming there's nothing else matching a dot followed by digits before the text you are interested in